# Get sum of group subset using pandas groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, subset-sum

I have a dataframe as shown. Using python, I want to get the sum of 'Value' for each 'Id' group upto the first occurrence of 'Stage' 12.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
               'Date': ['2020-04-23', '2020-04-25', '2020-04-28', '2020-04-20', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-05', '2020-05-12'],
               'Stage': [11, 12, 15, 11, 14, 12, 12],
               'Value': [5, 4, 6, 12, 2, 8, 3]})

Id  Date      Stage Value
 1  2020-04-23  11    5
 1  2020-04-25  12    4
 1  2020-04-28  15    6
 2  2020-04-20  11   12
 2  2020-05-01  14    2
 2  2020-08-05  12    8
 2  2020-05-12  12    3
```

**My desired output:**

```
Id  Value
 1  9
 2  22
```

Would be very thankful if someone could help.

Comment: please post the dataframes directly from output instead of images. its not possible for someone to reproduce your question otherwise.

Comment: good question , but do not post you data as pic ~

Comment: @BEN_YO Thanks, I have edited the question as asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try use the `groupby` `transform` `idxmax` filter the dataframe , then do another round of `groupby`

```
idx = df['Stage'].eq(12).groupby(df['id']).transform('idxmax')
output = df[df.index <= idx].groupby('id')['Value'].sum().reset_index()
```

---

Detail

the `transform` with `idxmax` will return the first index match with 12 for all the `groupby` row, then we need to filter the `df` with `index` less than that to get the data until the first 12 show up.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal ...why you think this not work .....idxmax return the first 12's index ...